# show that $x_n$ converges to root of alpha

Tags: real-analysis

I solved (a), (b) but
it's hard to show that c) is true.

(By intuition, since $x_1$ is larger root of $\alpha$, and all $x_n$ other than $x_1$ is $\lt$ $x_1$, I think all $x_n$ is in the interval (root of $\alpha$, $x_1$ )

I want to use theorem that if the sequence is monotonic and bounded, it converges,
but I'm not sure how to prove this is bounded!

Some helps please!

> Fix $\alpha>0$ and let $x_1>\sqrt\alpha$. Let $$x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(x_n+\frac{\alpha}{x_n}\right)\,,\,n\in\mathbb N$$
>
> - $\text{(a)}$ Show that $x_n>\sqrt\alpha$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.
> - $\text{(b)}$ Conclude that the sequence is monotonically decreasing.
> - $\text{(c)}$ Show that $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $\sqrt\alpha$.

Comment: You proved it is bounded below in part (a).

Comment: If it's bounded below and monotonically decreasing, it converges to the lower bound.

Comment: Oh. I thought I needed to show that it is bounded both above and below!

Comment: @InfimumMaximum The sequence is automatically bounded above by $x_1$ since the sequence is monotonically decreasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part (a) proves that $x_n$ is bounded (below). Part (b) proves that $x_n$ is monotonic(ally decreasing). Hence, $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$ exists. Let $x$ be what the sequence converges to. Note that:
$$
x=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n+1}
$$
Hence, we obtain:
$$ \begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n+1}&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left[\dfrac{x_n}{2}+ \dfrac{\alpha}{2x_n} \right] \\
x&=\dfrac{x}{2}+ \dfrac{\alpha}{2x} \\
2x^2&=x^2+ \alpha \\
x^2&=\alpha \\
x&=\pm \sqrt\alpha \\
\end{align*} $$
But since $x_n>0$ for all $n\in\Bbb{N}$, we reject the negative solution and conclude that $x_n$ converges to $\sqrt\alpha$, as desired.

Answer (score 2):

Since you showed in the first two parts that the sequence is bounded and monotonic, you know it has a limit $x.$ Taking $n\to\infty$ in the recursion, you have
$$x=\frac{1}{2}\left(x+\frac{\alpha}{x}\right).$$
Now just solve the equation for $x.$